# WCF Client Application not updating service reference after making changes in app.config

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-client

I'm trying to update three service references in a WCF app tied to a service. Two of the services appear to update, but the third freezes at "Downloading service information". All three services and their associated configs and bins are stored on the same server. What is the best practice and order to change configs on the app/update the service references.

Am I doing anything out of order? I usually 1. update the config file with endpoint changes (verifying the paths first), 2. Configure the service references for each endpoint, and 3. Update the references.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes something gets out of whack and the reference won't open. There is no danger in removing the reference and readding it. That always has fixed it for me.

Comment: Tried deleting them and upon attempting to re-add them, it never retrieves information from the server.

Comment: Can you load the definition files with a web browser?

Comment: I can get to the folder that holds the .svc files via a web browser.

Comment: What about the files themselves? If you can't load the wsdl with a browser, VS won't be able to either.

Comment: The wsdl for the client is stored locally, but I can view the XML for it in a browser.